# Android fragments shows the homescreen background on fragment close?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am opening a camera view in a fragment but when I replace that fragment it suddenly shows the homescreen and then the app continues. I have tried adding he fragment but it didnt solved my problem.Here is some code.
preview.camera.stopPreview();

```
try {
replaceTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
replaceTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, frag);
// replaceTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
replaceTransaction.commit();
//   preview.surfaceDestroyed();
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't know. Maybe problem in theme? I have such problem when have theme with transparent background or something like that.

Comment: but I also tested it with background colors but still the same result.